# javascript mouse event type help pls

Tags: javascript

```js
// **** Mouse Event

const btn = document.querySelector('#btnDeleteAll');


// ** Click event
btn.addEventListener('click',eventHandler);


function eventHandler(event)
{
    console.log(`event type : ${event.type}`);

}
```

```html
<button id="btnDeleteAll">Delete</button>
```

The output of the console.log section in the function only gives the type of the mouse event, not the left side, why?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "left side"?

Comment: hi @emirhan, I can see the code is working fine and outputs `event type : click`. Are you expecting some other output?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the `event.button` property for `0` to know if the left button was clicked:

From [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button):

- 0: Main button pressed, usually the left button or the un-initialized
  state
- 1: Auxiliary button pressed, usually the wheel button or the middle
  button (if present)
- 2: Secondary button pressed, usually the right button
- 3: Fourth button, typically the Browser Back button
- 4: Fifth button, typically the Browser Forward button

Also (FYI), when an element has an `id`, use `document.getElementById()`, which will be faster than `.querySelector()`.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btnDeleteAll');

btn.addEventListener('click',eventHandler);

function eventHandler(event){
    console.log(`event type : ${event.type}`, `event.button : ${event.button}`);
}

// For right-clicks
btn.addEventListener('contextmenu',function(event){
  // Prevent the native context menu from coming up (just for testing here)
  event.preventDefault();
  
  console.log(`event type : ${event.type}`, `event.button : ${event.button}`);
});
```

```html
<button id="btnDeleteAll">Delete</button>
```